# How does one test a Facebook Credits implementation on their staging app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-credits

A Facebook canvas app can only access the Facebook Credits APIs if the app has been whitelisted. To get whitelisted you need to fill out an application that registers your company and links a bank account.

Obviously I don't test new code on my production app -- I have a staging app, but the staging app is not whitelisted to access Facebook Credits, and I am trying to figure out what I should be doing or have missed to allow me to test my work in progress. Surely I don't have to go through the application and company registration again for my staging app, do I?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the person who fills out the company registration form has their account somehow linked to the company. That one person is able to set up credits on apps, but no one else. So the answer is to use a single, corporate login to do all your app setups and configs.

In my case, since this was not made clear or even implied by the signup process, one of our employees set that up under their personal account. The moral of the story is create a "company" account and do all app setups and configs under that login.